# The use of "expression" or "expressing" Is this the expressing or the expression of the problem?

Tags: word-choice

Do you present the re-telling of an old tale as "the expression of the tale or the expressing of the tale?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the actual writing, like a book, would be the expression of the tale.

Referring to the act of narration of the story, is somebody expressing the tale.

Personally, I prefer a different term that can mean both: The **telling** of the tale. The verb "tell" is specifically designed for the noun "tale".

> He told us the tale of King Arthur.
>
> This book is a telling of the story of King Arthur.
>
> This book tells the story of King Arthur.
>
> He was telling the tale of King Arthur.